# why 'rake test' is trying to connect to my development DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have my config/database.yml like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: psql_dev
  username: postgres
  min_messages: WARNING

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  min_messages: WARNING
```

When I run rake test:units, it reports an error:

> rake aborted!
>
> could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Why didn't it connect to my test DB(db/test.sqlite3).

and, If I run the test like this `rake test RAILS_ENV=test`, it works well.

Isn't `RAILS_ENV=test` the default setting for rake test?

I'm running `rails 2.3.5` with `ruby 1.8.7`, and my `$RAILS_ENV` is not defined in my shell.

Comment: echo $RAILS_ENV, does it way anything ? paste your Rakefile.

Comment: actually, I have no customized Rakefile. I just using the default rake file in rails. and, my $RAILS_ENV is null.

Comment: ok the do rake -T | grep test paste the result, btw does rake test works ?

Comment: OK, I got the problem. The root cause is that my DB connection for development in database.yml is pointing to an invalid psql server. And I guess the 'rake' will check the development DB for some update, it is still trying to using the test DB after checking the development DB. So the solution is to pointing to a valid DB for development.

Comment: interesting...but that does not explain why running with rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test works....why would rails check then ?

Comment: well, good point. I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that `rake test` depends on `rake db:test:prepare` which will attempt to load the current schema from the `development` database. That's how the test database gets updated when a migration is run on the development database

Answer (score 1):

do you have a test:units rake task? Run:

```
rake test
```

does that work? Also can you paste the output of:

```
rake -T | grep tests
```

Comment: looks like the 'rake test' ran my functional test successfully but failed on unit test. However, if I run 'rake test:functionals', it still report error as 'rake test:units' does.

Comment: maybe you are connecting to the db in your unit tests???? Look at your unit tests does anything requires a socket?

Comment: But, as I said, 'rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test' works well as expected.

Comment: I tried to change my config/database.yml, change the development section as same as test section. And it works well. So I can say that 'rake test' is connecting to the development DB.

Comment: just puts ENV['RAILS_ENV'] on some test to see what the value of RAILS_ENV is when rake test:units is ran. I doubt is anything other than test

Comment: I am not very familiar with rails 2.3.5, rails 3 sets rails env to test in test/test_helper.rb: first line is ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test" see if you have this file and if it does this.

Comment: yeah,  there is test/test_helper.rb, and it has ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test" in the first line. And I greped my folder, no other place is trying to change this value.

Comment: well breakpoint at the beggining of one of your tests and verify RAILS_ENV=test...I think the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I fixed this. Looks like the rake task will connect to development DB first to do some check.

Comment: Seems only explanation is that RAILS_ENV="development" before your test_helper.rb is loaded, and something is connecting to the db before that when test:units task is called, therefore it failed. When you set RAILS_ENV=test from command-line this didn't happen. I would actually find what is connecting to db before test_helper.rb is loaded.

Comment: OK, If you have any findings, please update to this answer. I will accept this.